# Generic formula to define how many ways of splitting a string into non-empty sets of different lengths where the group's order doesn't matter?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to find a generic formula to define how many ways of splitting a string into non-empty sets of different lengths where the group's order doesn't matter, but all letters must be used?

For example, a string 'abc' could be split:
'abc',
'a'|'bc',
'b'|'ac',
'c'|'ab',
'a'|'b'|'c',

*note I don't want to account for 'bc'|'a', as that is the same as 'a'|'bc'*

a string 'abcd' could be split:
'a'|'bcd',
'b'|'acd',
'c'|'abd',
'd'|'abc',
'ab'|'cd',
'ac'|'bd',
'ad'|'bc',
'a'|'bc'|'d',
... etc

I initially looked at 2^n and other combination formulas, but I'm struggling to get the answer?

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Comment: That's perfect, thanks, @MikeEarnest